# How to change a colour of a cell based on value in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to make a cell change colour when its value is under 100 however it does not change the color of the cell. I can default the colour of the entire grid however it is not working for individual cells. Please can someone lend a hand?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
            connection.Open();
            var SinglesDataTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(SinglesDataTable);
            connection.Close();
            DataColumn hourlyavg = SinglesDataTable.Columns.Add("Hourly Average", typeof(String));

            for (int i = 0; i < SinglesDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                object pickvalue = SinglesDataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                object timevalue = SinglesDataTable.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                double pickval1 = Convert.ToDouble(pickvalue);
                string timeS = "";
                timeS = timevalue.ToString();
                string timeSTrimmed = (timeS.Replace(":", ""));
                string timeSTrimmedHoursMins = (timeSTrimmed.Remove(timeSTrimmed.Length - 2));
                string timehourminindecimal = timeSTrimmedHoursMins.Insert(2, ".");
                double timeint = Convert.ToDouble(timehourminindecimal);
                if (timeint < 1)
                {
                    timeint = Math.Ceiling(timeint);

                }
                else
                {
                    timeint = timeint;
                }
                Convert.ToInt32(pickvalue);
                var hourlyratevar = pickval1 / timeint;
                double hourlyratedouble = Math.Round(hourlyratevar, 2);
                int hourlyraterounded = (int)Math.Ceiling(hourlyratedouble);
                SinglesDataTable.Rows[i][3] = hourlyraterounded;



                string hourlyavgstring = SinglesDataTable.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                double hourlyavgint = Convert.ToDouble(hourlyavgstring);


                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in SinglesGridView.Rows)
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value) > 100)
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }

                SinglesGridView.DataSource = SinglesDataTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in SinglesGridView.Rows)
    if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value) > 100)
        row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

there is another option: handle CellPainting event of DataGridView. E.g.:

```
private void SinglesGridView_CellPainting(object sender,
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && 
        e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
        Convert.ToInt32(SinglesGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value) > 100)
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I have tried this and it runs but still wont change the colour

Comment: @JonoA, did you try to set a checkPoint at `row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;`? if it doesn't get hit, the color will not change, obviously. such situation would mean that there is another problem. i also guess `SinglesGridView.DataSource = SinglesDataTable;` should go before foreach due to DataSource behavior. and both of them (datasource and foreach) should go outside(after) `for` loop

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved it ^_^ Sorry about late reply. Your help is greatly appreciated