# Changing Row Color of DataGridView Based on Cell Value

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datasource, bindingsource

I have Data Gridview with 2 columns namely *Filename* and *Status* .The DataGridview has a Datasource setup like this

```
 var bs = new BindingSourceAsync();
 bs.DataSource = data;
 dataGridView4.DataSource = bs;
```

The value of the Status Column is Updated using async-await method.When the Status Value is "Invalid" i need to change the the corresponding row color to red and green if its "Valid".

For this purpose i tried hooking to the CellValueChanged Event of the DataGridView

```
dataGridView4.CellValueChanged += DataGridView4_CellValueChanged;
```

But the Event is never fired.How can i solve this problem.Please advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a colour of a cell based on value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949397/how-to-change-a-colour-of-a-cell-based-on-value-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

yes, In RowDataBound for the gridview

```
    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // check if it is the DataRow not the header row
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Cell[1] is the cell contain the value for the condition
            if (Convert.ToInt16(e.Row.Cells[1].Text) < 10)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt16(e.Row.Cells[1].Text) < 30)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution is for a GridView, not a DataGridView.  This event doesn't exist in a DataGridView, or anything similar to it.